# I need to store an html input value in a javascript variable and show it in a table

Tags: javascript, html, input, html-table

I have the following variable in js:

```
var targetInput = {
  name: "1",
  targetTemperature: "20",
  targetHumidity: "48",
  targetLight: "1000",
  targetSoil: "750"
}
```

I have a table in html, from where I want to update this variable:

```
<tr>
   <th>Tube 1</th>
   <th>Temperature: <input id="temp" value="" type="number"></th>
   <th>Humidity: <input id="humi" value="" type="number"></th>
   <th>Light: <input id="light" value="" type="number"></th>
   <th>Soil: <input id="soil" value="" type="number"></th>
   <th><button onclick="newTarget()">Send</button></th>
</tr>
```

In my javascript I have tried to update the variable with this function:

```
function newTarget(){
  targetInput.targetTemperature = document.getElementById('temp').value
  targetInput.targetHumidity = document.getElementById('humi').value
  targetInput.targetLight = document.getElementById('light').value
  targetInput.targetSoil = document.getElementById('soil').value
  console.log(targetInput);
  addTableData();
}
```

The console.log works, the new values get shown. But then I try to show the data in a table, in a different html file:

```
<table class="table" id="target">
    <tr>
      <th>Tube number</th>
      <th id="number"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Target temperature</th>
      <th id="temperatureTable"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Target humidity</th>
      <th id="humidityTable"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Target soil moisture</th>
      <th id="soilTable"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Target light</th>
      <th id="lightTable"></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

I show the data from the first variable with this code:

```
function addTableData(){
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = targetInput.name;
  document.getElementById("temperatureTable").innerHTML = targetInput.targetTemperature;
  document.getElementById("humidityTable").innerHTML = targetInput.targetHumidity;
  document.getElementById("lightTable").innerHTML = targetInput.targetLight;
  document.getElementById("soilTable").innerHTML = targetInput.targetSoil;
  console.log("table data added");
}
```

I call this funtion at the end of my newTarget function, when the new data is added. The table however still shows the old data, not what I just added. How can I fix this?

Comment: you need to store the _new data_ somewhere coz it will disappear when a new page gets loaded or pass that _new data_ as a parameter to the new page, access it then display.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the key names in `targetInput` to match the `input` ids. Then, when the button is clicked, you can iterate over each `input` tag and update the input value from `targetInput` by using the id:

```
function newTarget(){
  var targetInput = {
    name: "1",
    temp: "20",
    humi: "48",
    light: "1000",
    soil: "750"
 }
  $('input').each(function(){
    $(this).val(targetInput[$(this).prop('id')]);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a different method to resolve your problem ( edit the target input and reCreate the table )

mothod 1 :

```
<table class="table" id="target">
     <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Tube number</th> <%--  Add the other Columns here --%>
       </tr>
     </thead>
</table>
<script>
    function setTableValues ()
    {
        var Tbody = '<tr>'+
         ' <tbody>'+
          '<th>'+targetInput.name+'</th>'+/// add the other columns
       '</tbody>'; 
        document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = Tbody;   
    }
</script>
```

method 2 :

you can user a DataTable of JQuery or Bootstrap .... 
like this :

```
<table class="table" id="target">

</table>
<script>
    var targetInputs = [{name: "1",
      targetTemperature: "20",
      targetHumidity: "48",
      targetLight: "1000",
      targetSoil: "750"
    }]; /// you add other target

     $('#target').DataTable({
                    data: targetInputs ,
                    "columns": [
                            { "title": "Tube number", "data": "name" },
                            { "title": "Target temperature", "data": "targetTemperature"},
                            { "title": "Target humidity", "data": "targetHumidity" },
                            { "title": "Target soil moisture", "data": "targetLight" },
                            { "title": "Target light", "data": "targetSoil" }
                    ],

                });
</script>
```